# Using List of IAM Policy Document Objects as AWS::Serverless::Function Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-visual-studio-toolkit, serverless-application-model

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) for `AWS::Serverless::Function` in the Serverless Application Model, it is possible to specify a list of IAM Policy Document Objects (PDO) for the `Policies` property of a Resource.

However, the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio is flagging a syntax error when I try to define an IAM PDO:
[image]

Here is a full example of my `Resources` section:

`"Resources": {
    "Example" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "Example::Example.Controllers.ExampleController::ExampleAction",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.0",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Policies": [{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        }],
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{id}",
              "Method": "GET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Is there something I'm getting wrong, or is there an issue with either SAM or the AWS Toolkit syntax validation?

Comment: Have you attempted to deploy this despite Visual Studio's objections? If it works, then it's a bug in whatever code inspector VS is using.  

Also, have you tried to make "Statements" value a list of objects instead of a single object? Long shot, but easy to try.

Comment: @Himal Hmmm... I tried this when I posted the issue and the deployment failed because of a syntax validation. Yesterday I updated the AWS Toolkit and now it works. So it seems you're right - there is a bug with the code inspector. Not sure where to report it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated the VS CloudFormation schema. The problem should go away the next time you restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your syntax is that it should be a statement array, because there can be multiple policies as below,

```
"Statement":[ 
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "*",
                "Resource": "*"
              }
            ]
```

example of having multiple policies will be as below,

```
"Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:${region}:*:table/${project}-songs-${dev}/*/*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem"                  ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:${region}:*:table/${project}-users-${dev}"
            },

         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is caused by syntax parsing issues in Visual Studio and the AWS Toolkit. I raised an issue on GitHub and you can track it here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1001

Comment: And for future reference https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues is the right place to report issues like this. I'll notice those question sooner.